# Was Buddha well known by western Romans in Late Antiquity?

Tags: roman-empire, buddhism

St. Augustine of Hippo was Manichean before he became a Christian. I have read in Wikipedia that [Mani, the prophet of Manichaeism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manichaeism), knew but rejected the doctrines of Buddha and that he died about a century before St. Augustine. There's also in Wikipedia information about Indian, maybe Buddhist, [ambassadors and travelers arriving to Rome and Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarmanochegas).

Is there any evidence to show that St. Augustine or some other common westerner Roman from his time (about 400 AD) was familiar with Buddha and his teachings? I want to exclude eastern Romans, like Syrians and Egyptians, from this question. When I say "common Roman" I mean ordinary, maybe educated people, like Augustine. I exclude politicians, merchants and ambassadors.

Comment: The article on Manichaesim that you link states these two things: 1. Manichaesim had Buddhist influences, and 2. St. Augustine of Hippo was a Manichaean before he converted to Christianity (after a disappointing meeting with a Manichaean Bishop). Considering that St. Augustine was well-read, it's quite possible that he knew about Buddha.

Comment: Related but different question: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/buddhists-in-ancient-alexandria-and-rome

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans I'd say that answer is perfectly valid for this. There's nothing that can be added there that would also answer this question.

Comment: [Hippo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippo_Regius) was a city in Algeria, North Africa, roughly corresponding to the modern day [Annaba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annaba). When you said that you want to exclude Egypt (and Syria), did you have all of Roman Africa in mind, or **strictly** its eastern parts ?

Comment: @Lucian The part of the empire the Romans called Africa was modern-day Tunisia and Algeria. I even think the ancient geographers of the classical age considered Egypt to be part of Asia. 

In any case Egypt was never considered part of the Western Roman Empire and the question I asked was about the Western Romans.

Comment: @Ginasius: Asia [spanned](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Strabo/1D*.html) between the Nile (or Red Sea) and the Indus, with Africa (Libya) to its west, and [India](http://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/ancient/strabo-geog-book15-india.asp) to (or in) its east.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not: [this article](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2015/10/how-david-hume-helped-me-solve-my-midlife-crisis/403195/) by Alison Gopnik in The Atlantic suggests that Buddhism was barely known in Western Europe until the 1700s.

Comment: Given the massive cultural changes occuring in Europe between the fall of the Romans empire and the Renaissance, I doubt that a lack of knowledge on Buddhism in Europe around 1700 gives us any information about the state of knowledge on this subject in the western Roman empire

Comment: Certainly, but in light of how well documented the Roman Empire was, I'd personally be surprised if institutional knowledge of a major world religion could be lost in this fashion.